# What is happening when I am adding a load capacitor in CMOS inverter?

Tags: voltage, inverter, cmos, capacitance, vlsi

I want to simulate an inverter with CMOS. When I added a load capacitance and plotted the output voltage. I saw a sharp voltage graph so I have changed the dimensions of the transistors and got the graph that is shown below.

[image] [image]

What is happening when I am adding a load capacitance?

Here is the circuit with capacitance:

[image]

Comment: It takes time to charge up, is that surprising?

Comment: Yes, because I have started to learn two weeks ago. And I do not have enough background but I am trying to catch up ... so I need help to understand some basic stuff. If you can explain I will be extremely glad.

Comment: Google RC circuits, there are hundreds of sites with far better explanations than I could give you.

Comment: What were the transistor dimensions for the top graph?

Comment: You discovered why people want as little capacitance as possible. Capacitance slows down the circuit as it takes time to charge the capacitor and that steals from your output. In the top graph the capacitance is OK but in the bottom it is too large for your signal frequency and you never reach a stable output.

Comment: @DaveTweed sorry for late reply , the dimensions are the same as shown in the schematics.

Comment: ??? You said you changed the dimensions between the two runs. I'm confused.

Comment: Oh yes, sorry again :D The dimension for pmos is W= 20u W= 1u and for nmos is the same.

Answer (score 2):

When you add a capacitor, it charges via the pull-up PMOS to output a logic '1'. If the PMOS has a definite ON-resistance, R and if the capacitance of the capacitor = C, RC time constant will decide the rise time while driving output '1'. That's why that slope is there.

Similarly, the capacitor discharges through through the pull-down NMOS to drive the output to logic '0'. The ON-resistance of NMOS will decide the RC time constant this time, and hence the fall time to reach logic '0'.

The dimensions of the transistors will decide its resistances. W/L ratio of PMOS to NMOS is typically kept at 2.5 to achieve equal rise and fall times.